# find files within a specific directory structure but a variable parent directory structure

Tags: shell, find, csh

I want to use the find command in linux to find a specific file nested within a specific directory structure, say `dir1/dir2/reqdfile`.

But this directory structure can itself be nested within any parent directory structure.

Is it possible to a search like?

```
find directory_to_search -name "**/dir1/dir2/reqdfile"
```

What is the exact syntax?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `-path` instead of `-name`:

```
find directory_to_search -path "*/dir1/dir2/reqdfile"
```

Note that there's only one asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a quick and dirty alternative would be to use grep. Though it's not as clean for find specifically, thanks to the -path option, many similar cases can be solved like so:

```
find directory | grep "/dir1/dir2/reqdfile$"
```