# Grep on specific directory structures

Tags: command-line, search, grep

What I'm trying to accomplish:

Search for the regular expression `\b\$\w+` in all `.php` files that fall under this directory structure:

```
foo/templates/*.php
bar/templates/*.php
<something>/templates/*.php
```

**Edit:** I should state that my higher-level goal is to find unique PHP variables within files

What I tried:

```bash
grep '\b\$\w+' **/templates/*.php
grep '\b\$\w+' */templates/*.php
grep '\b\$\w+' **/templates/**.php
```

None of them seem to produce the expected results. What is the correct syntax to do this?

Additionally it would be nice to "group by" or "select distinct" (so for instance `$_GET` would only show up once even if there's 180 instances in the file) if that's possible.

---

I've already read these answers which led me to try the above commands:

- [find files within a specific directory structure but a variable parent directory structure](https://superuser.com/questions/238429/find-files-within-a-specific-directory-structure-but-a-variable-parent-directory)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/55325/how-to-use-grep-command-to-find-text-including-subdirectories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
grep -oE '\$\w+' */templates/*.php | sort -u
```

Notes:

- The `-o` option tells `grep` to print only the matching portions of the line, not the whole line.  This should give you the names of all `$`-style variables.
- `sort -u` sorts and removes duplicates so each variable name should appear in the output only once.
- The `\w` construct that you were using requires extended regex.  Therefore, the `-E` option was added.
- The use of `\b` for word boundaries is problematic here because `$` is not a valid "word" character and hence does not begin a word as `\b` would understand it.  Therefore, `\b` would only match if a word happened to end just before the `$` as in `a$b` but not `a $b`.  `\b` was removed from the code above.

Comment: Do you happen to know which package `sort` is in so I can install it via apt-get? I'm using Linux Mint

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Mint is part of the Debian family.  On Debian, `/usr/bin/sort` is in `coreutils`.  So use: `apt-get install coreutils`. `coreutils`, being core utilities, though, really should be installed by default.  As it says on [LinuxMint.com](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/coreutils): "This package contains the basic file, shell and text manipulation utilities which are expected to exist on every operating system."